# NgInx container is not loading css and js file when it call php-fpm container

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-8, nginx-config

I have this Nginx file conf for my nginx container

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/html;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

charset utf-8;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off;}

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).*{
    deny all;
}
```

}

When I running all containers it works, and my nginx is calling php cgi in **laravel:9000**, is php-fpm, but css and js file I am getting 404 htpp code.

Anyine can help to fix that?

NGINX DOCKERFILE

```
FROM nginx:1.15.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

RUN mkdir /var/www/html -p && touch /var/www/html/index.php
```

Laravel DOCKERFILE

```
FROM php:7.1.3-cli as builder
WORKDIR /var/www/laravel
COPY . .
RUN cp .env.example .env
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libzip-dev -y && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN  php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
     php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
     php composer-setup.php && \
     php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN php composer.phar config --no-plugins allow-plugins.kylekatarnls/update-helper false && \
    php composer.phar upgrade

FROM php:7.1.3-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html
COPY --from=builder /var/www/laravel .
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN ln -s public html
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: are the css and js files available in the nginx container?

Comment: All Css and js file are coming from laravel app

Comment: yes but nginx is responsible for serving those files and therefore needs access to them directly, not via the laravel container. fpm is only responsible for serving .php files

Comment: can explain how I can do that? this the main problem

Comment: all file are in my laravel container served in laravel:9000

Comment: see my docker files @apokryfos above

Comment: Basically something like and `COPY . .` in the nginx container so it knows what static files are there

Comment: facing same issue